# Consulta 5 tablas relacionadas mysql con condición

Tags: php, mysql

estoy con un proyecto en php y debo hace una consulta de 5 trabablas relacionadas entre si

trabajo, usuario, trabajo_detalle, paciente, producto y voy a devolver una tabla de los trabajos y su detalle

campos tabla trabajo:

id | código | fecha_r | id_usuario | total

campos tabla usuario :

id | nombre| apellido

campos tabla paciente :

id | nombre| apellido

campos tabla producto

id | nombre| precio

campos tabla trabajo_detalle:

id | trabajo_id| id_producto| paciente_id | fecha_e | cantidad | total

quiero obtener

trabajo.codigo | usuario.nombre | usuario.apellido | paciente.nombre | paciente.apellido | producto.nombre | trabajo_detalle.cantidad | trabajo_detalle.total cuando fecha_e este vacia es dcir no se ha entregado el trabajo

mi poblema radica en que no logro unir llego solo hasta union de dos tablas, cuando voy a unir tercera tabla me da error, las trabajas estan correctamente relacionadas.

consulta hasta cual llego pero con error

```
SELECT codigo,fecha_r, usuario.nombre as unombre,usuario.apellido as uapellido, trabajo_detalle.cantidad as td_cantidad
FROM ((trabajo
INNER JOIN usuario ON trabajo.usuario_id = usuario.id)
INNER JOIN trabajo_detalle.trabajo_id=trabajo.id  )
```

Error:

```
SELECT codigo,fecha_r, usuario.nombre as unombre,usuario.apellido as uapellido, trabajo_detalle.cantidad as td_cantidad
FROM ((trabajo
INNER JOIN usuario ON trabajo.usuario_id = usuario.id)
INNER JOIN trabajo_detalle.trabajo_id=trabajo.id  ) LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '.id  ) LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 4
```

Tengo usuario (mis clientes) tengo productos tengo pacientes recibo un trabajo de mi cliente, cargo en trabajo, el id usuario, fecha recepcion y demas sin importancia , en detalle_trabajo cargo , para que paciente (paciente_id), que producto (producto_id), cantidad

Comment: En el segundo JOIN no estás utilizando el ON. Si estás uniendo las 5 tablas con JOIN no hace falta que utilices paréntesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que el problema lo estas teniendo con la segunda unión de las tablas, ya que te faltaba colocar el nombre de la tabla. Te dejo la modificación del código.

Gracias

```
    SELECT codigo,fecha_r, usuario.nombre as unombre,usuario.apellido as uapellido, trabajo_detalle.cantidad as td_cantidad
FROM trabajo
INNER JOIN usuario ON trabajo.usuario_id = usuario.id
INNER JOIN trabajo_detalle ON trabajo_detalle.trabajo_id=trabajo.id
```

Comment: muchas gracias, puede unir las 5 tablas y obtener lo que queria